# Is it ok to keep foreground service alive to wait for internet connection?

Tags: android

**Scenario**: I have an upload queue that is run in a foreground service. When the phone loses internet connection, I simply change the message of the foreground notification. The service stops any uploads & simply waits for internet to be reconnected. There's a broadcast receiver implemented in the service that listens to connectivity. When internet is connected again, the service simply continues uploading.

The goal here is to ensure that uploads will always continue after internet is connected.

**Question**: Is it a concern to let the foreground service stay alive for the sake of waiting for internet connectivity? Is there a huge risk of the broadcast receiver actually not receiving the message that internet is reconnected (thus causing the foreground service to stay alive forever)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 As far i know it is worst scenario to keep foreground service alive 
 to wait for internet connection. Who knows this waiting time,
 it may be hours, days... so who will wait till that time.


 Save your data in local database which you have to upload.
 Use Brodcaste reciever for the action of internet connectivity,
 on connecting to internet use service for uploading the data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's bad. If you're holding a WakeLock then you might be keeping the phone awake longer than it needs to be. At the very least you're using more resources than needed.

Use a JobService to Schedule a job to run when you have a connection:

```
// Make a component that points to your (new) SchedulerService (Implements JobService).
// Your scheduler service will be called when network is available.
ComponentName component = new ComponentName( getPackageName(),
                    SchedulerService.class.getName()));

JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo(JOB_ID, component);
// ... Set some other constraints
builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);

// Schedule it
mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
mJobScheduler.schedule( builder.build() );
```

Some time later, when there is a network available your SchedulerService will get it's `onStartJob(JobParameters params)` method called. From here you'll be able to kick start your Exist "upload service" to continue the upload.

Read more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html

Android JetPack users: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/